# Amazon Simple Email Service full message ID

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, email

When sent email through [symfony mailer](https://github.com/symfony/mailer) with Amazon SES settings had two cases
(`uuid` parts of strings not exact in my examples + the first case is an Amazon SES sandbox case):

| settings `host` | message ID received from Amazon SES at the sent stage | message ID inside received email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com | 01000145618123e4-013f8b9d-8af5-4ae5-ac57-2a886dacc0ef-000000 | 01000145618123e4-013f8b9d-8af5-4ae5-ac57-2a886dacc0ef-000000@email.amazonses.com |
| email-smtp.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com | 01000181718123e4-013f8b9d-8af5-4ae5-ac57-2a886dacc0ef-000000 | 01000181718123e4-013f8b9d-8af5-4ae5-ac57-2a886dacc0ef-000000@eu-north-1.amazonses.com |

So, in the above examples `setting hosts => received message ID` related as:

`email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com  => email.amazonses.com`
`email-smtp.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com => eu-north-1.amazonses.com`

I need store full message ID in a database during sent stage, so, the full message ID should be something like:
`message ID received from Amazon SES at the sent stage` + `part of settings host`.

Both cases have the same parts before `@` and different ones after `@`

So, in the second case:
`stored to DB full message ID` === `message ID inside received email`
And, in the first case:
`stored to DB full message ID` !== `message ID inside received email`

Is there reliable way to detect full message ID at the sent stage?
Maybe there's no point in trying to handle it in case of sandbox?

Comment: Looks like the same UUID in both of your examples. Are they not the same if you just remove everything after the `@`?

Comment: @jordanm thank you, I edited the post: in both my examples the UUID are the same.
They are the same if I remove everithing after the `@`